# Return object to end parallel while True loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I am writing a little API to make my python command line output look just a little nicer. But there is still a big problem, because I would like to be able to call a function like `display_loading_until_event(text)` which should:

1. Immediately return a way to "finish" the loading animation
2. Update the loading animation every 0.25 seconds.

I also tried using `Process` from the `multiprocessing` library but it doesn't seem to work:

```
from time import sleep

def display_loading_until_event(message):
    from multiprocessing import Process
    
    class Stop:
       def __init__(self):
            self.run = True

    class LoadingAnimationProcess(Process):
        def __init__(self, stopper, *args, **kwargs):
            Process.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.stop = stopper

        def run(self):
            def get_loading(position):
                return positions[position] # Returns the way the loading animation looks like (position: ["\", "|", "-"])

            print(get_loading(0), end=message) # Simplified version
            pos = 0
            while self.stop.run:
                sleep(0.25)
                pos = pos + 1
                print("\r" + get_loading(pos) + message, end="") # Again, simplified
                if pos == len(positions) - 1:
                    pos = -1
                sleep(0.25)
            print("\r" + "✔" + message) # Prints ✔ to signal that the loading is done

    stopper = Stop()

    loading = LoadingAnimationProcess(stopper)
    loading.start() # Starts the process
    def stop():
        stopper.run = False
        sleep(1)
        # loading.join() ???
    return stop # This therefore returns a function to stop the loading, right?

# So this should in theory work:
positions = ["\\", "|", "-"]
endfnc = display_loading_until_event("Hello loading")
sleep(4)
endfnc()
# And now the loading SHOULD STOP
```

This code is just an example, the real code is a bit more complex but this should do.
The loading animation doesn't work on powershell or so (`\r` is the thing that breaks it.)

The current code works and all things after the `display_loading_until_event` call get executed but the loading doesn't stop.

And also I don't think that this is the right way to do this...

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood what you were asking — will delete my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of does the job:
[How to end a while loop in another Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107143/how-to-end-a-while-loop-in-another-thread)

I just return the "condition.set" method and it works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).