# How to end a while loop in another Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I would like to end a `while True` loop in another thread in python:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

condition = False

def check_sth():
    while True:
        if condition:
            print("Condition met, ending")
            break
        else:
            sleep(0.25)
            do_sth()  # Do something everytime the condition is not met

Thread(target=check_sth(), args=(,)).start()
sleep(2)
condition = False
#  Doesn't print "Condition met..."
```

Or is there a way to simply `kill` the created thread, so I can do the following:

```
thread = Thread(target=check_sth(), args=(,))
thread.start()
thread.kill() # (?)
```

Ways to do this using `asyncio` or another framework are also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note your code isn't passing the arguments properly when creating the `Thread`, and never set the `condition` boolean variable to `True`.

Here's how to fix those things *and* be able to stop the `while` loop in the other thread. Instead of a simple boolean variable, it uses an [`Threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) object to control the loop and allow it to be set true from the main thread in a thread-safe way.

#### Code

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Event, Thread

condition = Event()

def do_sth():
    print("truckin' ...")

def check_sth():
    while not condition.is_set():
        sleep(0.25)
        do_sth()  # Do something everytime the condition is not set.

    print("Condition met, ending.")


Thread(target=check_sth, args=()).start()
sleep(2)
condition.set()  # End while loop.
```

#### Output

```
truckin' ...
truckin' ...
truckin' ...
truckin' ...
truckin' ...
truckin' ...
truckin' ...
truckin' ...
Condition met, ending.
```

Comment: I've been looking around for an answer to work with key presses that start and end a function when you press a key. This worked for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Create a Queue `from Queue import Queue` and pass it to the thread func. Inside the while loop read from the queue (using `get`). The main body of the code should `put` something in the queue that will flag the thread to stop.

Read more [here](https://www.troyfawkes.com/learn-python-multithreading-queues-basics/).

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to simply kill the...thread...?

It is practically never a smart idea to let one thread kill another. The reason is simple: Threads communicate with each other by altering the state of shared program variables.  If thread A simply kills thread B without any form of synchronization between them, then there is no way for thread A to know, when is a *safe time* to kill thread B such that thread B will not leave things in an inconsistent/invalid state.

But, on the other hand, if you synchronize them, then you've made it possible for thread A to *ask* thread B to clean up and terminate itself.

Threads within the same program should always *cooperate* with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling and passing the result of your `check_sth` function as the target argument to `Thread`. This is why your code doesn't work. This is what you should do instead:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

condition = False

def check_sth():
    while True:
        if condition:
            print("Condition met, ending")
            break
        else:
            sleep(0.25)
            do_sth()  # Do something everytime the condition is not met

Thread(target=check_sth).start()
sleep(2)
condition = True
```

Note I replaced `check_sth()` with `check_sth`. This way I'm passing the actual function, and not its result.