# Execute other statements while a 'While' loop runs in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, while-loop

I'm writing a small application on Python.

I have a `While` loop executing indefinitely while a global variable is set to True, but I want to be able to set this same variable as False clicking another button (I'm using dearpygui to make a interface).

Here's the main function code:

```
import pyautogui
import time

global enabled
enabled = True

def stopautoclick():
    listglobals = globals()
    listglobals["enabled"] = False

def autoclick(button, delay, coordX, coordY):
    listglobals = globals()
    mousebutton = button
    match mousebutton:
        case "Esquerdo":
            mousebutton = "left";
        case "Direito":
            mousebutton =  "right";
        case "Centro":
            mousebutton = "middle";
    print(mousebutton)
    time.sleep(delay)
    while listglobals["enabled"]:       
            pyautogui.click(x=coordX, y=coordY, button=mousebutton);
            time.sleep(delay);
```

See that `enabled` global variable?
So, I created a button to stop that `while` iteration by setting this global variable to `False`, like this:

```
dpg.add_button(label="Parar Auto Click", callback=lambda: stopautoclick)
```

Problem is nothing in my code executes while the `while` loop iterates. Therefore, when I click the stop button, it doesn't execute anything and the value of the global variable `enabled` is not changed.

Even tried using the `asyncio` library to make the code execute asynchronously, but no success.

**TL;DR: I want to be able to stop a loop (be a `while` or a `for` loop, doesn't matter) by clicking a button in my window interface, but while the loop is running, nothing else executes.**

Comment: Why are you using `globals()`? You can refer to global variables as normal variables: `while enabled:`

Comment: If you want to assign the global variable in a function, use `global enabled` followed by `enabled = False`

Comment: I'm using global variables to access it on other files. Don't know if it's necessary, but your comments does not solve my issue, since I cannot modify the value of any variable while the loops is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the knowledge of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69108071/12531776) on another question, I was able to solve my issue.

In short, I started the `autoclick` function using a `Thread` and used an `Event()` to perform the loop (`while not condition.is_set()`), and on the my "stop button" I just called `condition.set()`

This is the code:
`autoclick.py`:

```
import pyautogui
import time
from threading import Event

enabled = Event()

def autoclick(button, delay, coordX, coordY):
    mousebutton = button
    match mousebutton:
        case "Esquerdo":
            mousebutton = "left";
        case "Direito":
            mousebutton =  "right";
        case "Centro":
            mousebutton = "middle";
    print(mousebutton)
    time.sleep(delay)
    while not enabled.is_set():   
        print(enabled)
        pyautogui.click(x=coordX, y=coordY, button=mousebutton);
        time.sleep(delay);
```

`pyclick_ui.py`:

```
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg
from threading import Event, Thread

from delayWithMessage import delayWithMessage
from autoclick import *
from getmousecoords import getmousecoords

[...some code]

def handleAutoClickButton(mousebutton, delay, coordx, coordy):
    tStartAutoclick = Thread(target=autoclick, args=(mousebutton, delay, coordx, coordy)).start()

def main():

   [...some code]

   dpg.add_button(label="Iniciar Auto Click", callback=lambda btn, delay, cX, cY: handleAutoClickButton(listglobals["mouseButton"], listglobals["clickDelay"], listglobals["coordX"], listglobals["coordY"]), tag="btnstart")
   dpg.add_button(enabled=False, label="Parar Auto Click", callback=lambda: enabled.set(), tag="btnstop")

[...rest of the code]
```

That way, when I click the second button, the `enabled` variable is `set()` and then the `while` loop will stop.

If any of you have a better approach, I'll be happy to read.